# When to close or flag a question that "doesn't belong there"?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, off-topic

With a few reputation points came to me the option to close off-topic questions and not just flag them.

I thought this meant flagging them was now useless and was just giving more work to people reviewing the flags.

But now I see that high reputation users go on flagging posts, or so it seems from their very high flag number. So I suppose there is a reason to keep flagging.

Is there somewhere a guide on when to close  or flag (or both) off-topic questions and why ?

Comment: See [Close Questions Privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) and [How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)

Comment: The second link seems to perfectly answer (I did search...). Should I delete this question ? BTW I think this guide (second link) should be somehow put in the privileges guide.

Comment: It is, it's linked at the end of that *When should I close a question?* section...

Comment: Ok, so I'm just bad at reading documentation. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should flag a question when it is :

- spam
- offensive, abusive, or hate speech
- it is very low quality
- other (*a custom message that you write , that a moderator will read and take action on*)

You should close a question when it is :

- a duplicate
- off-topic
- unclear what the questioner is asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion based

You do not need to worry about accidentally flagging a question instead of closing it, since if you click flag and choose a close reason instead of a flag reason, it will have you vote to close instead of flagging it.